# Set Match Reference to true at CSV Import Prestashop

Tags: prestashop, csv-import

Can someone please tell me where i can set the Match Reference Function to true instead of false by Standard?

I already tried it in AdminImportController in ImportProducts Function

by setting

$match_ref = Tools::getValue('match_ref');

to

$match_ref = Tools::getValue('match_ref', true);

But without Luck the button still shows No by Standard [here you find a picture of what button is meaned](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nmy1S.jpg)

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting that value has nothing to do with default button. And there is no setting for it so it's always shown by default as `No`.

What you need to do is open file `administration/themes/default/template/controllers/import/helpers/form/form.tpl` and find at the bottom the javascript part.

Insert somewhere inside `$(document).ready()` function

```
$('#match_ref').parent().trigger('click');
```

This will force the button to be set to `Yes` everytime you load product import options.

*PS: I don't recommend editing core files or templates, so I'd advise you to leave the original template alone and copy it to* `override/controllers/admin/templates/import/helpers/form/`
*and make your modifications in this file.*